# Content type fields+customXMLParts+ document custom properties

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, office365, office-js

I have associated my custom content type with my document library in sharepoint, and each content type is connected with a template.

Is there a way that I can access content fields values with 'office js' so that I can update my content fields values by code?

I tried 'CSOM', I can access the fields and can edit, however when I save I got error message saying the document is in use or is locked by another person.

Note: with 'context.document.properties' I can only access the buildin properties while with 'context.document.properties.customproperties' I can only access 'ContentTypeId'.

Please someone share some lights, thanks!

[ctfields show up in document properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmVqL.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clearly written to understand what you are looking for. The document library properties don't show up as part of default or custom properties. These are simply key:value pairs defined in the document (built-in or custom). You'd need to look at the [custom XML parts](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/customxmlpartcollection.md) to access the SharePoint document library properties that are saved to the document. I'm not very sure about the Word APIs. For that you may need to look under the v1.0 [API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/customxmlnode.getxmlasync.md) set to access doc library properties

Comment: Thank you Sudhi! Sorry that my question confused you. I'm a new sharepoint developer and just got my first assignment from work- to create an office addin which can be integrated in sharepoint. I myself is so confused too... Anyway, back to the question, I think the content type related custom XML part is automatically created when you create a word document, but how can I programmticlly access the it? I mean when you can't use 'getByNamespaceAsync' or 'getByIdAsync' to get the specific XML part? Or we need to create another custom XML part to include all the content type fields? Thanks!

Comment: Also, @Sudhi Ramamurthy content type fields show in document properties and 'ContentTypeId' show in custom properties. Please refer the image I upladed in my post.

Comment: The properties shown in the red-box from your picture is likely from SharePoint document library. It is added by SharePoint and for Word, the only way to access it is through custom XML [collection](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/customxmlparts.customxmlparts.md). Looks like the API doesn't have properties on the XML to navigate. So, you may need to know the name-space of the XML part to query by. You can crack open your docx file (rename as .zip and browse) and figure out the namespace you SharePoint is using to add the XML part and then use the API.

Comment: thank you @Sudhi Ramamurthy for your helpful input, I now can finnaly edit my content type fileds with my addin!

Comment: Hey @Sudhi Ramamurthy, I'm now facing another problem. After I modified the document metadata I have to refresh my page url in order to pass new document context to my addin so that I can have access to the correspoding content type document properties. Could you give some suggestion about how to refresh document context or just refresh the customXMLnodes?Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Any changes to the document should be picked-up immediately by add-in code. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: I would think the same, all the changes should be pickedup immediately, that's what async means, right? However, for example, when I change the document's content type with my addin, the addin only gets the "old"  context and shows the content type fields from the old content type, if I need to show or edit the content type fileds from the new content type, I need to reload the whole page to pass the new context to my addin.

Comment: Would be helpful to log a new issue with code snippets. Also, please share the environment details - O365 vs. on-prem, is it MSA, which OS you are testing on, etc.