# Customxmlnode: is there a way to get a single node using office js?

Tags: javascript, office-js

I noticed that with VBO you can call the method `getSingleNode` to get a specific node object, is it possible to do something similar with office js?

Also, I have a radio button value in my Word metadata, I managed to access its `customxmlnode` object, then I used `setTextsync` method to change its value from `true` to `false`, but the new value I get for my radio button metadata is empty. Other text type metadata could be edited correctly though.
Could anyone give some suggestions?

```
function EditCTF() {
  //$("#fields").css({ display: "" });
  Word.run(function(context) {
    context.document.properties.title = $("#Title").val();
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByNamespaceAsync(
      "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties",
      function(asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.value.length > 0) {
          var xmlPart = asyncResult.value[0];

          xmlPart.getNodesAsync("*/*", function(nodeResults) {
            console.log(nodeResults.value.length);
            for (i = 0; i < nodeResults.value.length; i++) {
              var node = nodeResults.value[i];
              node.getTextAsync({ asyncContext: "StateNormal" }, function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(result.value);
              });

              console.log("NewValue");

              if (node.baseName == "Address") {
                node.setTextAsync(
                  $("#Address").val(),
                  {
                    asyncContext: "StateNormal"
                  },
                  function(newresult) {}
                );
              }

              if (node.baseName == "MainContactPerson") {
                node.setTextAsync(
                  $("#Main Contact Person").val(),
                  {
                    asyncContext: "StateNormal"
                  },
                  function(newresult) {}
                );
              }

              if (node.baseName == "GDPR") {
                node.setTextAsync(
                  "true",
                  {
                    asyncContext: "StateNormal"
                  },
                  function(newresult) {
                    console.log(newresult);
                    console.log(newresult.value);
                  }
                );
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    );
    return context.sync().then(function() {});
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you add a code sample, demonstrating what you did / tried to do?

Comment: Thank you @Michael Zlatkovsky - Microsoft for your reply. I have just added my code in my post. I would like to update my content type fields value with my word addin. Content type fields are from sharepoint document libray. More information could be refered to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642434/content-type-fieldscustomxmlparts-document-custom-properties.

Comment: I just think if it's possible to get a single node, then I can avoid these if statements. And my GDPR value is a radion button with potiential "true" or "false" values. Hope now I have explained clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The correct XPATH format is not an intuitive format, and it does not help that the Microsoft API documentation provide dumb examples that use wildcard (*/*) xpaths, like so:

```
xmlPart.getNodesAsync('*', function (nodeResults)
```

OfficeJS (or perhaps, SharePoint) injects namespace aliases into the mix (ie /ns3:...), so you were on the right track, but to get the 'CGI_Address' SharePoint document property, you need this XPATH syntax:

```
var xpath = "/ns0:properties[1]/documentManagement[1]/ns3:CGI_Address[1]";
xmlPart.getNodesAsync(xpath, ...);
```

GOTCHA: When making significant schema changes to the SharePoint content types that the Word document is based on, it may suddenly change the namespace alias from "ns3" to "ns4" or indeed, from "ns4" back to "ns3" like what happened to me today - go figure?!?

And it seems that the OfficeJS API does not properly implement XPATH, as trying to wildcard the namespace alias (so it can accept /ns3 or /ns4 etc) with /*:CGI_Address[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath) doesn't work.
SO Reference (as to why it should work) - [how to ignore namespaces with XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440451/how-to-ignore-namespaces-with-xpath)

Comment: I just logged in to stack overflow to upvote your answer! Extremely helpful. Just a question when documentation of Microsoft about is too vague. How did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the XPATH expression you send in the  xmlPart.getNodesAsync("*/*", function(nodeResults)  method.  The first parameter is an XPath expression you can use to get the single node you need.

Comment: Thank you @Juan Balmori! The thing is my custom XML Parts are auto generated, I have no idea what is the XPath exactly. Would you help out to point out what is my XPAth for the CGI_Address node? Thanks! Please refer to the code below.

Comment: <p:properties xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/metadata/properties" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xmlns:pc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2007/PartnerControls">
  <documentManagement>
    <CGI_Address xmlns="3d84821b-860c-40ef-af9a-16e6c620590f">Göteborg</CGI_Address>
    <CGI_MainContactPerson xmlns="3d84821b-860c-40ef-af9a-16e6c620590f">KJKJK</CGI_MainContactPerson>
    <CGI_OfficePhone xmlns="3d84821b-860c-40ef-af9a-16e6c620590f"> 46874985</CGI_OfficePhone>
  </documentManagement>
</p:properties>

Comment: I learned XML dom today and I noticed I can use xml methods like xmlDoc.getElementByTagName to select a specific node. So problem solved:) Thank you for your help.

Comment: yes you can also use any XML library to get access to them, but be careful and test it in multiple browsers. (not all libraries are compatible in all browsers)

Comment: Hey @Juan Balmori, I still wonder if I don't covert my xml string to dom object, how can I otherwise get a specific node? Like in my code example, I tried ' xmlPart.getNodesAsync('documentManagement/CGI_MainContactPerson' , function (nodeResult) {...}'  but the nodeResult I got is 'OSF.DDA.AsyncResult {value: Array(0), status: "succeeded"}
status : "succeeded"  value:[]  __proto__ : Object', this is not what I expected. What should the correct XPath be then?